# allowsEdgeAntialiasing not working on iOS17

Tags: ios, uikit, antialiasing, ios17

I have some `UIImageView` rotated (using the `transform` property) in an app and I have noticed that on iOS17 the edges are heavily aliased, this is something I addressed originally by setting `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` to true in the layer of those views and it has been working in other versions of iOS just fine.

This is how the view is set up

```
        self.imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        self.imageView.backgroundColor = theme.BackgroundColor
        self.imageView.layer.borderWidth = theme.BorderSize
        self.imageView.alpha = theme.Alpha
        self.imageView.layer.borderColor = theme.BorderColor.cgColor
        self.imageView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
```

I tried setting the antialiasing globally in the `.info` file, but the result is the same. Setting `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` to false in the view doesn't change the render result.

iOS 16 screenshot:

[image: iOS 16]

iOS 17 screenshot:

[image: iOS 17]

---

**Edit**

Quick complete example showing the issue:

```
class EdgeAntialiasingVC: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        let imageViewA = UIImageView()
        let imageViewB = UIImageView()
        
        let viewA = UIView()
        let viewB = UIView()
        
        let labelA = UILabel()
        let labelB = UILabel()
        
        [imageViewA, imageViewB, viewA, viewB].forEach { v in
            v.backgroundColor = .red
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            v.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-.pi * 0.05, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20.0),
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30.0),
            ])
        }
        for (v, s) in zip([labelA, labelB], ["UIImageView", "UIView"]) {
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            v.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14.0, weight: .light)
            v.text = s
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            labelA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            labelA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            imageViewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelA.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            imageViewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelA.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            imageViewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            imageViewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            labelB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewA.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            labelB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            viewA.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelB.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            viewB.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: labelB.bottomAnchor, constant: 4.0),
            viewA.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            viewB.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewA.trailingAnchor, constant: 20.0),

        ])
        
        imageViewB.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
        viewB.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true

    }
    
}
```

Two `UIImageView`s, and two `UIView`s ... right-side views have `.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true`:

on iOS 16 - `UIImageView` and `UIView` both antialias the edges:

[image]

on iOS 17 - **only** `UIView` antialiases the edges:

[image]

Comment: Show us examples of what you're seeing.

Comment: I am seeing aliased edges, on iOS 16 the same view and code looks smooth. I will post some pictures.

Comment: @DonMag updated with screenshots

Comment: I edited your question with a quick example that anyone can copy/paste/run and see exactly what the issue is. Makes it much more likely folks will give it a try and report back with either confirmation or a solution.

Comment: This appears to be either a) **a bug**, or b) an **undocumented change**.

Comment: Thanks, I filled a bug report, because I can't find an alternative api to enable this on `UIImageView`

Comment: Curiously... if we load an image and set `viewB.layer.contents = img.cgImage` we **do** get edge antialiasing.